# Not displaying special characters imported from a file

Tags: sql-server, import, bulk-insert, encoding

The scenario is a SQL Server instance, a database which is data fed using BULK INSERT operations mainly, and some of the texts inserted contain special characters like `ñ` because I am working in a Spanish environment.

So, after the first little tests I realize these special characters are not being displayed correctly when I run a simple `select`, so I start checking everything I can think of:

- File encoding: the file to be bulk-inserted has the right encoding: ANSI
- Database encoding: the database has the right encoding (thank god): `select collation_name from sys.databases where name='DBNAME';` results in `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

  - Latin1: charset used. This suits me fine enough
  - General: nothing really interesting here
  - CP1: this means that it uses the codepage 1 which, in short, means the codepage 1252 <=> codepage used for the encoding WIN-1252 which is fairly similar to Latin1
  - CI: case insensitive
  - AS: Accent sensitive, so á is different from a
- export data to file and check: file encoding is ANSI **but** the data is not displayed correctly, there are no special characters, instead I find some other characters that make the text hard to read.

With these tests, I conclude that the data **is not being stored correctly**, and that is why it is not being displayed and exported correctly. Almost every solution I have found on the internet suggests using `nvarchar` instead of `varchar` for string datatype fields, but that does not solve this scenario. What is it that is sabotaging my insertions?

Comment: @TypoCube Excuse me, I am still kind of new to the community. What was wrong with the title I provided? I bear no ill will, it's just curiosity and I don't want to have someone behind my work correcting my mistakes all the time

Comment: It wasn't bad. But we generally don't put the DBMS in the title, unless it's necessary (like "How to migrate from SQL Server to Postgres?"). It's in the tag, so it's enough. People can "follow" tags they like.

Comment: And the "[solved]" is not necessary either. If you have an accepted answer, it's solved ;) You probably can't accept it immediately due to rep restrictions but that's ok, too. It gives time for others to see the question and possibly add some more info or answer (questions with accepted answer get sorted lower than ones without accepted answers)

Comment: Plus I didn't find anything else to edit in your question, so it was good. To be honest, if it hadn't that "[solved]" I probably wouldn't have touched it at all ;)

Comment: See my answer to a related meta q: [how to undo edits someone else did on my own posts?](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2581/how-to-undo-edits-someone-else-did-on-my-own-posts/2584#2584) My point is that it's not our questions and answers any more. Anyone else can edit them. And we can go and edit other questions and answers if we think they need improvement ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If characters are being imported incorrectly, then there is a problem with one (or both) of the following areas, as this is really a two-step process:

1. BCP / BULK INSERT does not know how the file is encoded and is interpreting it incorrectly
2. The destination column is `VARCHAR` (or `CHAR` {or `TEXT`, but don't use `TEXT`} ) and the Collation of that destination *column* (not database) uses a code page that does not have a mapping for the incorrectly imported character(s).

It is important to note here that the default Collation for the database where the import table resides is not relevant. The only Collation that matters here is the Collation of each particular string column being imported into. And the Collation of each and every string column can be different, and none of them need to be the same as the database's default Collation. It is just typical to have the Collation of most columns in a database match the database's default as that will be the Collation used when creating new tables and columns and not specifying a Collation via the `COLLATE` keyword.

**Step 1: File Encoding**
BCP / BULK INSERT (or most any other code reading a file) will not know what encoding a file is using unless the file is using one of the few encodings to have a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). But Extended ASCII encodings don't use byte order marks and thus cannot be programmatically determined (at least not with certainty). When using Extended ASCII encodings, you either need to specify the code page or else a default will be assumed.

As per the MSDN page for the [bcp Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx), under the **-C** option:

> OEM  ->  Default code page used by the client. This is the default code page used if **-C** is not specified.

You can determine the default code page by opening a command prompt and running either `mode` or `chcp` (I prefer `chcp` as it also allows for changing the code page if you pass in a value).

If your default code page is 850 and yet the file was saved with an encoding of Windows-1252 Latin1 (ANSI), then there could easily be problems interpreting the file since the character mappings are not the same between those two code pages. This has nothing to do with SQL Server in any way.

The `ñ` character has a value of 241 on code page 1252. BUT, on code page 850 that same character has a value of 164. The file, regardless of anything else, is a series of bytes, and one of those bytes has a decimal value of 241 (because when it was saved, it was told to use code page 1252 which determined that `ñ` needed to be stored as 241). Now, when BCP reads the file, if it is using the default MS-DOS code page of 850, that same byte value of 241 maps to character `±`. If you were to specify a code page of either `ACP` or `1252` (same thing) via the `-C` switch, then BCP will know that a byte of value 241 is actually `ñ`. Or, you could specify a code page of 1255 (Windows Hebrew), then BCP / BULK INSERT will interpret that same byte value of 241 as being character `ס`.

**Step 2: Destination Column Datatype and Collation**

Once BCP / BULK INSERT (or any client app) reads the data in, it exists as those mappings, not just the base byte values. Whatever characters were read into BCP / BULK INSERT will be stored in the destination column *as that character*, as long as that character can be mapped in the destination datatype and Collation. A destination datatype of `NVARCHAR`, `NCHAR`, and `NTEXT` (but don't use `NTEXT`) can hold all characters, so it won't matter what the Collation is. But, if the destination datatype is `VARCHAR`, `CHAR`, or `TEXT` then the Collation will determine the code page which in turn determines the character mappings. If the destination datatype is one of those last 3 mentioned *and* uses Collation associated with the same code page used for the file, then everything should work just fine. Or, if the Collation is associated with a different code page, then an attempt will be made to map the *character*, not the byte value.

Meaning, if BCP / BULK INSERT is working with a code page of 1252 and a character of `ñ` (value 241 on code page 1252), then if you import that into a `VARCHAR` column with a Collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS` -- which uses code page 850 -- then you will see a character of `ñ` (same character, but value 164 on code page 850) instead of `±`, which has the same 241 value on code page 850. But, if you import into a `VARCHAR` column with a Collation of `Hebrew_CI_AS` -- which uses code page 1255 -- then you will see `?` instead of `ס` (value 241 on code page 1255) as there is no mapping for `ñ` on code page 1255.

Comment: I find _extremely_ interesting the way `NVARCHAR` and its kind work compared to its "N-less" versions, as that is the behaviour I always expected/was used to. Also that feat about attempting to map existing characters from two similar encodings seems pretty smart although can lead to confusing transcriptions if the conditions are not met. I now see clearly how my issue had to do with the way bcp/bulk insert was inyerpreting my file and that alone, while also learned a bunch about the matter. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

For those who may come up with a problem similar to mine, the thing that worked for me was related to the codepage system. I'll explain in further detail:

The collation of the database stated that the database used the codepage 1252 and after checking my computers active codepage (run `cmd` and then, inside the cmd, `mode`) I found it was 850, so a conflict must have been going on!
If the computer is not able to print my special characters correctly, then the database is going to store whatever silly strings my computer prints to it.

I added the option `CODEPAGE=ACP`, which forces the bulk insert to use the codepage of the sql server, and everything worked out just fine :)

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for contributing so that others could get help in similar situations. There is a slight issue with this answer, though. While it produced the correct result for you, the explanation is incorrect and might not work for others. I am adding an answer now to explain what is going on here.

Comment: That would be really nice of you :D my answer and explanation are my best guess as to what was going on and how this solved it, but I don't really have the confidence to back my words strongly